# How can I force administrator to provide a reason when cancelling a user account

Tags: users

I would like to find a way for drupal site administrator to provide a reason when an account has been cancelled / blocked.

I would need a radio list such as below, then an automatic email is sent with the details of the option chosen by the admin.

- Your email address is not a personal address issued by your company
  E.G. a.name@yourcompany.co.uk
- You did not supply your full name
- You did not supply your company name
- You did not supply a full address
- You did not supply your telephone number

Answer (score 0):

In User fields, add field of type: List Text with checkboxes radio button as widget

Use the [Filed Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module so only admins can see this user field.

Download [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and enable Rules UI

#### Create a New Rule

React on: After Updating an Existing User Account

Add Condition: Data Comparison >> account-unchanged:status >> Operator: Equals **DATA Value: Blocked**

Add Action >> Send Mail >> Body: [user:name] was blocked because [user:field-example]